# PHP - making an api call to telestream with php

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to do an api call to [telestream cloud api](https://cloud.telestream.net/docs#api) by using php. I am not sure how to do this, they only have examples for Python, Ruby and GO. Not sure how to set this up with PHP. I have tried to do this to [get the videos](https://cloud.telestream.net/docs#videos) from my factory that I have on their telestream cloud:

```
  $service_url = 'http://api-eu-west.cloud.telestream.net/videos.json';
  $curl = curl_init($service_url);
  $curl_post_data = [
          'access_key' => 'my-access-key',
          'secret_key' => 'my-secret-key',
          'api_host' => 'api.cloud.telestream.net',
          'api_port' => '443',
          'factory_id' => 'my_factory_id',
  ];
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
  $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
  if ($curl_response === false) {
      $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
      curl_close($curl);
  }
  curl_close($curl);
  $decoded = json_decode($curl_response);
```

But, that doesn't work, if I do:

```
dd(curl_getinfo($curl));
```

I get the error:

> curl_getinfo(): supplied resource is not a valid cURL handle resource

Is there any example of how can I make this call with PHP?

Comment: what happens when you run this, have you debugged it to see whats failing?

Comment: I don't get any errors, but I get null as a result.

Comment: Have you inspected the Response Headers? It might help in debugging.

Comment: I have done ```dd(curl_getinfo($curl));``` and got ```curl_getinfo(): supplied resource is not a valid cURL handle resource```